# Unexpected junk after else?

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran (I mean I started 5 mins ago) and i have been messing around and I know how to do prints start/end programs and the if part of the if statement.  The problem I am having, though, is with the else part.  It keeps coming up with the error:

```
ELSE() print *, "x did not = 1"
    1
Error: Unexpected junk after ELSE statement at (1)
```

Here is my code:

```
program hello
x = 1
IF(x==1) print *, "Hello"
IF(x==1) x=2
IF(x==1) print *, "Oh it didnt work..."
ELSE() print *, "x did not = 1 yay it worked"
end program hello
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the parentheses after your `ELSE`? The error message is pointing right at them. I assume you have a Fortran manual online or hardcopy to reference for proper syntax.

Comment: At first I wrote it without the parentheses but the same error occurred.  I was just seeing if it made an difference, but it didn't.

Comment: Given that you started learning the language "minutes ago" I would recommend checking the documentation rather than just wild guessing. You'll learn the language faster and more accurately. You probably would have found the answer faster than posting here.

Comment: `ELSE` is part of a block construct. So, the immediately preceding if statement needs a `then` after it and the print statement goes on its own line. Then for the else, no parenthesis, the print statement goes on the next line (hopefully indented so it looks good), and an `endif` statement on a line after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct structure for your example code should be similar to:

```
        program hello

        x = 1
        if( x == 1) print *, 'hello'
        if( x == 1) x=2
 25     if( x == 1) then
            print *, "oh it didn't work..."
        else
            print *, "x did not = 1 yay it worked"
        endif

        end program hello
```

Notice that the if statement in line 25 is followed by the 'then' keyword and you options are divided by the else statement.

Also the line number is not necessary. I just used it here so I could reference the line in my answer.

Comment: You don't need line numbers here. Also, the poster uses free-form, is there any reason to switch to fixed-form? I would also suggest to add `implicit none` and to declare x.

Comment: i just used he line number here so i  could reference the line in my answer.

Comment: @jmh thanks so much it worked!  So just to clarify, I need a 'then' after my last if before I put an "else"?

Comment: Yes. You can do an if with no 'then' as in the first 2 lines above or you can do whats known as an 'if-then-else' construction as we used.  You may also have an if-then-endif with no else.

Comment: What code editor are you using?  Many are fortran syntax aware and will make approprite hilights where they appear.